# PrimeVue Menubar

Tags: css, menubar, primevue

I created a drop down menu with menubar. However I have custumization problems :

- The transparency is well done, but the size of the horizontal items is too hight (and so not vertically centered. The required height is thirty pixels all inclusive ;
  (just resolved with *height: 30px;* in passive mode (neither hover nor seleted). The selection "Button" item in the horizontal menu remains too hight
- The vertical menu items are too separated from each over and the width of the vertical menus too narow ;
- The movement in the verticals menu items not be materialized (with a blue color) as it is in the horizontal menu;
- Impossible to move to a submenu with a mouse. Only with keybord arrows. Why ?

I tried a long time the css with modification of the "theme.css" of the saga-blue theme, but nothing to do nothing works except the css lines included in my code :

Code:

```
.p-menubar {
     background: transparent;
     padding: 0;
     height: 30px;
}
```

What are the particular css elements and clauses to modify ?

Comment: I'd need to see some html as well in order to get a good grasp of how everything's connected.

Comment: @Tomas,<br/>Hello,<br/>The html code does nothing. It's primary generated which refers to its own JS creations.<br/>the JS code conforms to the documentation (although cross référence aren't yet implemented (not the goal here)).<br/>The source of the theme is in <code>[project localization]\node_modules\primevue\resources\themes\saga-blue</code><br/>That of primevue in <code>[project localisation]\node_modules\primevue\resources</code><br/>(file//:J:/VANDEKERKHOVE/MesImages/Capture menubar 1.jpg)

Comment: Alright, was asking so I could reproduce it, play around and see if I could find a solution. Could you perhaps create a Fiddle or SandBox? Would help tremendously to figure out a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, using Chrome's inspector, I ended up discovering the CSS classes involved. By groping on the values I got about what I wanted.

*The impacted code:*

**In the vue.js file:**

```
<div id="menuU" class="user-menu" v-show="isvisible()">
         <Menubar:model="items" class="p-menubar"></Menubar>
</div>
```

the v-show parameter is application specific and not given here.

**In css:**

```
.menu-utilisateur {
     background-color: lightgrey;
     height: 30px;
 }

.p-menubar {
     background-color: lightgrey;
     padding: 0px;
     height: 30px;
}

 .p-menubar .p-menubar-root-list > .p-menuitem > .p-menuitem-link {
     padding: 0.5rem 1rem !important;
 }

 .p-menubar .p-menuitem-link {
     padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem !important;
 }
```

Don't forget the !important. It overwrites the default values.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31644033)